# Mongoose: creating keys dynamically with Schema.Types.Mixed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my Schema:

```
var Account = new Schema({
    username: String,
    likes: Schema.Types.Mixed
})
```

Here I'm adding *'someProperty'* property to likes. Everything works just fine.

```
var conditions = {'_id':req.body.id};
var update = {'$set':{'likes.someProperty': req.body.something}};
var callback = function (err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err);
};
users.update(conditions, update, callback);
```

After update my document:

```
'username': Fat Gandalf,
'likes': {
           someProperty: '100'
         }
```

My problem is that I don't know the name of 'someProperty'. I need to create it dynamically somehow:

```
var temp = 'likes.' + req.body.propertyName; // -- > 'likes.anything'
var update = {'$set':{temp: req.body.something}};
```

The above example doesn't work. God damn it! Need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to construct the field object as follows:

```
var conditions = { "_id": req.body.id },
    update = { "$set": {} };

update["$set"]["likes."+req.body.propertyName] = req.body.something;
Users.update(conditions, update, callback);
```

Or using [**computed property names (ES6)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
var conditions = { "_id": req.body.id },
    update = { 
        "$set": {
            ["likes."+req.body.propertyName]: req.body.something
        } 
    };
Users.update(conditions, update, callback);
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you, good sir! I feel so grateful to you, is there any way I can help you out with something?

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov No worries, always happy to help :)